# Invalid format: "19690321" is too short

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I am trying to convert yyyyMMdd format to yyyy/MM/dd format using pig for that i have written below code.

**Code:**

```
STOCK_A = LOAD '/user/root/xxxx/*' USING PigStorage('|'); 
data = FILTER STOCK_A BY ($1 matches '.*ID.*'); 
MSH_DATA = FOREACH data GENERATE ToDate($8,'yyyy/MM/dd','UTC') AS dob;
```

When i am trying to dump the result i am getting below error.

> ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.pigstats.SimplePigStats - ERROR 0:
>   Exception while executing [POUserFunc (Name:
>   POUserFunc(org.apache.pig.builtin.ToDate3ARGS)[datetime] - scope-209
>   Operator Key: scope-209) children: null at []]:
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid format: "19690321" is too
>   short

**Sample:**

```
EXVORV@#PDULD21F|ID|1|483|1020783||EXVORV@#PDULD||19690321|F|
```

$8 seems valid to me i am not able to locate the reason the issue is coming. Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You use :

```
ToDate($8,'yyyy/MM/dd','UTC')
```

but the format is

```
19690321
```

so you should have

```
ToDate($8,'yyyyMMdd','UTC')
```

Comment: but i want the date to be in yyyy/MM/dd format from yyyyMMdd. how can i achieve that ?

Comment: The todate is to convert your string to date. Pig will know that the format is date, you will be able to do stuff on that ( compute age, select line between 2 date ...)  If you want to print back your date, you have to convert back to string with ToString. You can use "ToString(yourDate,'yyyy/MM/dd')"  for instance.  or even "ToString(yourDate,'ww-yyyy')" to have the week number.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is most likely because of the load statement.Since you are not specifying the schema the datatype by default will be `bytearray`. You will have to convert it to `chararray` before passing the field to ToDate

```
STOCK_A = LOAD '/user/root/xxxx/*' USING PigStorage('|'); 
data = FILTER STOCK_A BY ($1 matches '.*ID.*'); 
MSH_DATA = FOREACH data GENERATE ToDate((chararray)$8,'yyyy/MM/dd','UTC') AS dob;
```